# If a high attrition rate is observed in a workforce, how do you state it as a characteristic of a generalized individual? Highly Mobile?

Tags: grammatical-number, expressions

Here's the context:
Statement: Attrition among the X workforce is high.

Now I want to specify this at an individual's context. As in:
"The X worker is **__**"
What is the correct term here?
The X worker is highly mobile?

This is for a presentation slide and I'm striving for brevity.
Attrition here means that workers change jobs often, not that they migrate.

Comment: Hi scorpion. Welcome to ELU. *Attrition* in this context means *The gradual reduction of a workforce by employees' leaving and not being replaced rather than by their being laid off,* so you should probably forget about alternatives to "mobile" (although "flexible" might be better) and ask about alternatives to "attrition".

Comment: If, per FumbleFingers' definition, attrition is high because the workers leave and aren't replaced, the question is why workers leave in the first place; answering that may lead you to the word you seek.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome :) 
I believe your definition is correct. The original quote was "the overall attrition rate for the workforce has doubled". I see Gnawme's point. However, the word would then be "greedy" :D Money is the primary reason they leave. I think the term I'm looking for may be related to concepts like loyalty to the employer. I just feel there's a specific term here that's not popping in to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

"Has limited tenure" or "transient" might work.

*The typical X worker has limited tenure.*

*The X worker is transient.*

Comment: Interesting. However, would that imply that the worker is not leaving by choice. A plumber maybe transient only because you'd hire one for a one off job. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I don't think that would imply leaving by choice or not, only that the stay is temporary, or the length of the stay is limited.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you mean a high staff "turnover", which is a steady state or dynamic equilibrium, rather than the reduction caused by attrition without replacement.

But in either case you could say the workers are "restless" or "footloose".

Comment: Yup, turnover is the notion we are dealing with. I like the term "restless". However, I have a slight doubt whether it goes with the general tone of the presentation which is highly academic. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons why people quit their jobs: to find a place with a lower cost of living; or they're having children and want to move back closer to family; or they get hired away in a competitive job market; or the work-schedule flexibility and/or benefits offered by another company are superior to what they have now; or another company seems more stable and lesss likely to be "downsizing" or "rightsizing"; or they're impatient regarding advancement and promotion and another company offers them a "step up"; and so on.

A term that ignores all of those reasons and concentrates solely upon "able and willing and likely to leave for greener pastures, whatever their definition of "greener pastures" happens to be, is **nomadic**.

> The X employee is highly **nomadic**.